# Infopath 2010 Submit Button issue

Tags: infopath

I have a serious problem with the Infopath 2010 List form i deployed recently. Every time I edit a previously filled form, it creates a new Infopath 2010 form .

How can I restrict the creation of new forms from the edited one? I want to be able to edit a form and have it published without creating a new form.

Comment: do you edit in design mode?

Comment: Yes i do Gwyn. Kindly give me step by step instructions about how to achieve this .

Comment: @MelvinMetieh Make a comment instead of answering...

Comment: first I need to know, what the problem is. Do you get any error message?

Comment: No i do not get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Check you have got "Overwrite form" ticked for the submit.
Check that the way you create the filename name for form doesn't change depending on the time saved/submitted, or similar.